# Groovy xml parsing

Tags: java, xml, groovy

Hi i'm new to groovy and I have a misunderstanding of how groovy parse xml

```
<schema-definition name="Standard" > 
  <field-type name="Standard:Integer" descr="A whole number." base-type="long"/> 
  <field-type name="Standard:Boolean" descr="A boolean value." base-type="boolean"/> 
  <field-type name="Standard:String" descr="A string" base-type="string"/> 
</schema-definition>
```

When i try

```
document = groovy.xml.DOMBuilder.parse(new FileReader('D:/test.xml'))
rootElement = document.documentElement
use(groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory)
{
    field-types=rootElement.field-type
    println field-types
}
```

I doesn't even compile:
(field - types) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line: 13 column: 20

Comment: This looks like a cumbersom way to do it. Why not give XMLSlurper a go instead. It's so much more Groovy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't compile because the "-" in field-types is an operator and therefore cannot be part of a name. Also, if you access the tag field-type you must use quotes, like this:

```
def fieldTypes = rootElement."field-type"
```